# AndroidManifest.xml can not resolve symbol TODO style and drawable

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-manifest

I wrote a simple app in flutter and then after some research I changed the name and icon. After changing these two I got errors which I never had before on AndroidManifest.xml. I tried few things after research on thew Net. (like invalidate cache and restart) but still I get those errors. I would appreciate every help.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.sarisayfav1"
    android:versionCode="TODO"
    android:versionName="TODO">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="Akçakale_Sarı_Sayfa"
        android:icon="@android:mipmap/sym_def_app_icon"
        tools:ignore="NewApi">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            tools:targetApi="honeycomb">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you tried using "@mipmap/ic_launcher" this path for icon? Just replace the ic_launcher with your new icon. The new icon name should also be ic_laucher.

Comment: Did this my friend yet still i get the same error.

Comment: Can you post the detailed log here. It will give a better insight into what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:versionCode="TODO"
android:versionName="TODO"
```

remove these 2 lines.
TODO is not a recognized android version Name. flutter will set them automatically

Comment: did this too my friend. still i get these errors. **Cannot resolve symbol '@mipmap/ic_launcher'** **Cannot resolve symbol '@style/LaunchTheme'** **Cannot resolve symbol '@style/NormalTheme'** **Cannot resolve symbol '@drawable/launch_background'**

Comment: @teacher-in-code can you post the error message?

Comment: to change the Apps Label you only have to change the "android:label" tag.  to change the icon most easiest way is to use this https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html and replace the default icons. i think you have created an invalid theme and its why the compilations is failing.

Comment: my suggestion is creating an empty flutter project and move your dart files there and then do what I have instructed. remember to also update the pubspec file too